# How to add small messages in shelve in perforce?

Tags: git, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I usually use GIT for my local versioning. The server uses perforce. Although i have a good set of small commits in git and i like it so that i can see the messages with commits. This helps in recollecting a lot of steps taken.

But then for the server, i just `keep shelving the file to the same pending changelist` in the perforce. I do not revert back the files. This is the option given in perforce client.

`How can i save my changes with the messages` ?

Am i required to use something other than shelve ?

Comment: Does anything speak against submitting the small changes in separate small perforce changelists?

Comment: @pitseeker Is the standard way of working with perforce ? Are changelists synonamous to commit in GIT ?

Comment: Well, git manages "commits" locally, so nobody else sees them unless they're propagated to other places whereas perforce has a central repository, so it's not really comparable. But if you ignore this fact, then yes, a perforce-submit (aka changelist) is the same as a commit in git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be making multiple shelves, not updating a single existing shelf.

Alternatively, create a branch for your work, and submit each incremental change as a separate changelist. Since you're working in a separate branch, your work isn't affecting others until you integrate the work from your branch back to the parent codeline.

In general, I find that as soon as I want to track more than a single set of changes (i.e., more than a single git commit), it's time to create a branch.

Perforce has a variety of features that can be used efficiently in this case; contact your Perforce administrator at your site for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan's answer is probably the most straightforward option. You could also look into using [P4 Sandbox](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/p4v_sandbox.html), which is basically a different way of accomplishing the same thing.